# Junit execution failure using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit4

I have been facing the below issue while running Junit test cases (single or all the test cases)

```
Class not found com.account.api.bo.TestSomeClass
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.account.api.bo.TestSomeClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:688)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Class not found com.account.api.bo.TestSomeClass
```

Please note that I am building the project using ANT and junit execution is working fine using ANT.

Comment: Classpath errors would cause your eclipse project to fail compilation much before you attempt to run the test case. Have you found and fixed them all? You're probably missing some jars in the eclipse project build path, while the ant build path is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
com.account.api.bo.TestSomeClass
```

Is not defined in your eclipse's classpath, but it is probably in ANT. You need to right click on your project and then go to Build Path, add lib that contains TestSomeClass.

Comment: I have tried adding the jar and also the class folder of the test classes. Now I am receiving the below error.

`java.lang.ArrayStoreException:`

Comment: Than it means that probably you have resolved issue from the question and you have another, different one. [ArrayStoreException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html) - you can find an example of code that generates this error in documentation, probably you have problem with your implementation.

Comment: I am still facing the same issue of ArrayStoreException. I will post a new question related to the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to capitalize your first character of class name ?
not testSomeClass,

```
com.account.api.bo.TestSomeClass
```

Comment: It is not working even after changing the class name as mentioned above. Is there any specific change required in classpath?

Comment: How is this irrelevant to the question that was asked? At best this can be a comment. If you have nothing to say, don't say anything